# Col should collapse and float left

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have following setup (I know it's not best looking, but it serves the case). I have multiple col-md-4 tags. As soon as the height of the left one is bigger than the others, the one in the second row is in the middle, but it should be on the left under the first one with the TestTT... string.

https://www.bootply.com/HJbiqZXmkE

The thing is I am using AngularJS and loop with ngFor through multiple things, so I can't statically add a row-tag after the third one, because I don't know how many will be displayed.

Comment: do you want the content to wrap for the forth div?

Comment: you do know bootstrap grid system, each row have max 12 col right?

Comment: you can add `min-height: 50px;` to `.col-md-4` to make sure they align the way you want. https://www.bootply.com/Xw1HLTVhNO

Comment: @techLove This is my problem, I can't set any height value, because I don't know, how much text they will each contain. In your bootply add more text to the first col. At some point it will have a bigger height than the others and in the next line the next col will be in the middle.

Comment: Seems bit too complex for bootstrap only solution, so I would recommend to take a look at CSS `flex-box`property or some Masonry framework, https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate div in loop it take default css. Contain in div is uneven, due to this have bootstrap adjust its self, shows you best result,this is intended. You have to set definite height for your div, this might screw you responsive, you may have to write @media code with custom css. since you want use 4 space without using row, you can do like this

```
<div class="col-md-4 customCss">Content1</div>
<div class="col-md-4 customCss">Content2</div>
<div class="col-md-4 customCss">Content3</div>
<div class="col-md-4 customCss">Content4</div>
```

in css

```
.customCss{
  min-height:50px;// you desirable properties 
}
```

**UPDATED**

I have used php to do, you can implement using your language in angular

assuming $rows is my array

```
  <?php $rows =  array(array('id'=>'a'), array('id'=>'b'),array('id'=>'c'), array('id'=>'d'),array('id'=>'e')); 
  $i=0; // counter 
  foreach ($rows as $row){  
  if ($i%3==0) { // if counter is multiple of 3 ?>
      <div class="row">
  <?php } ?>
       <div class="col-md-4">
         Content
       </div>        
  <?php $i++; ?>
  <?php if($i%3==0) { // if counter is multiple of 3 ?>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
 <?php } ?>
 <?php if($i%3!=0) { // put closing div if loop is not exactly a multiple of 3 ?>
       </div>
  <?php  } ?>
```

let me know if you are not getting

Comment: This is my problem, I can't set any height value, because I don't know, how much text they will each contain.

Comment: you have to assume some height.

Comment: Ok I fixed it giving always the 3rd div an attribute of "clear: left;"